# Why is it showing password while logging in?

Tags: plot-explanation, why-him

In [Why Him?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Why_Him%3F), Ned Fleming is trying to log into Laird Mayhew's computer. He tries to enter some random passwords like **stephaniesboobs** etc.

[image]

Then why is it showing the characters instead of dots while logging in?

Comment: ..that would be for the sake of the audience. Dots are hard to laugh at, especially in a screenshot.

Comment: May the programmer used input type=text instead of type=password :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How would you **know** what he tried, if asteriscs were shown instead of the real password?

As stated in comments: it would not be funny  at all without actually showing the password.

By the way, this is a common trope when showing someone guessing passwords, not only when making jokes about it...

Answer (score -1):

It is often possible to set up login screens to show password for the sake of people who are not good at typing and need to verify that they did it correctly.